# Rep bonus for associating accounts... ...lost if you associate early?

Tags: discussion, reputation, association

It's annoying having no rep on the sister sites to S.O. (including here/M.S.O.), but I've heard that if you're over some number, 200 or something, on SO, you get rep when you associate.

?Unfortunately? I hate having multiple accounts, so without knowing that I associated all the other SO sister site accounts with my SO account.

I've been over 200 rep on SO, used some of it up on a bounty, so now I've dropped below 200 again.

Will I get that rep for sister sites at some point from gaining rep on SO, so that I can make upvotes and the like on sister sites, or have I lost it?

If I have lost it, would disassociating accounts on sister sites until I have another 200 rep on SO, and then recreating them and relinking them let me skip having to build up rep again elsewhere?

Comment: Well, I guess I'll just disassociate and reassociate later, just in case that helps.  I'd prefer not to have to jump through more hoops than the bare minimum I need to.

Comment: We'll see if it works.  *smiles*

Comment: Sweet, it works, as a workaround, to unauthenticate then reauthenticate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, this worked to get me the rep benefit on superuser/serverfault/meta, once I got 200 rep on stackoverflow:

Get your rep over 200 on one of the sites, and then unassociate the other accounts, and reassociate them.

Could be dealt with in a smoother way, but it worked well enough for me.

Answer (score 8):

If the 200-rep min is to avoid gaming the system, then maybe users should get the rep bonus retroactively when they surpass minimum requirements. That way, people are encourage to associate their accounts a soon as possible without worrying when is the "best" time to link their accounts.

The 100-point bonus was started to encourage users to associate their accounts because it was good for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe just something that gets checked specifically when a user requests their account page, so that if any go above 100, they all do.  *smiles*  Would make more sense than the disassociation-until-above-200 that I'm doing now.  :p

Answer (score 3):

When you associate, it does a check to see if you have more than or equal to 200 rep. If so, you get the 100 rep bonus.

So no you wont get 100 rep on the sister sites when you go past 200 on SO after you associate.

Comment: Ok, I figured that the site isn't checking continually.  If I disassociate and then reassociate later, will that get me the rep to skip repeating the same low level processes on the sister sites?