# Transfer points between sites

Tags: support, reputation

I have over 1000 points at Stack Overflow, but only 1 point on Server Fault.  It's so painful asking questions on Server Fault.

Since I write a lot of code for an enterprise environment, I have the occasional server question.

Shouldn't I get some credit for being good at Stack Overflow? It wouldn't even let me post two URLs on my last question.

Answer (score 10):

[Associate your accounts](https://serverfault.com/users/13219?tab=accounts#sort-top) and you'll get 100 more on SF.

Comment: and if you didn't get the bonus when you associated (remember, one of the accounts has to have +200 rep), unassociate and then re-associate and you'll get it.

Comment: In my real experience it quite bad design that "one of the accounts has to have +200 rep" as {I on Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/users/2255628/destiny-architect } have enough rep(finally!) to operate barely(comment & vote-up,specifically 57pts) but creating an associated account I get just 1 pt(so~= to spam bot!) causing{no basics http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15117/should-so-rep-be-considered-in-su-and-sf#comment-764746 }. IMHO,a NOT bad solution wd be to ALWAYS transfer to any new account the max points of any associated account up to a limit say 150(so to vote-down,too).

Answer (score 5):

It is good that the sites are different.

Your reputation should not affect the quality of answers to the questions you ask (nor to the answers you give to other questions).

Reputation is nice and lets people know you are serious, but not really anything else. I have a load of reputation on Superuser.com, however, I don't see why my answer should be taken any more seriously than a new user's answer with just one reputation.

To me personally, reputation is simply a "I am being appreciated / spending time helping people is not going to waste".

I have a load of reputation on SuperUser right now, but I am not exactly the best programmer in the world - It can be abused and people can transfer points for the careers site and look better in an area than they are... then again, if anyone looked in more detail, they may wonder why you have 20k reputation and only one answer!...

At the end of the day, I just see a lot of trouble with little to no positives for it.

Comment: Although you can still use it for bounties, which i think apart from the gamification aspect of them is the only really practical use of the points.

Answer (score 1):

Across all sites, you don't need any more than 1 rep to post a question. The sites are designed to be painless for all users.

It's so easy that it allows unregistered users to post their questions without having to grind up for rep points.

To post a question on any of the trilogy sites, just click on the **Ask Question** button top right of the screen and fill out the necessary details.

And, since you can comment on your own question, as well as any [answers on your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/new-user-comment-clarification), you can get around the "can't post links" thing by using the comments.

And, [as John Rasch said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34860/transfer-points-between-sites/34861#34861), the good user credit you get comes in the form of a 100 rep power-up when you associate your accounts and one of them [has more than 200 points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29295/rep-bonus-for-associating-accounts-lost-if-you-associate-early).