# Post how much rep you're going to lose with the new re-calc!

Tags: discussion, reputation-recalc

Before anyone says that I'm whining about the re-calc, let me just say that I'm not. I actually do like it.
But I also like stats (and being nosy), so post how much rep you will lose:

---

```
SITE  Current  - Recalc  = LOST
-------------------------------
SO       8430  -   6156  = 2274
SF        426  -    314  =  112
SU        584  -    205  =  379
MSO      1372  -    765  =  607
-------------------------------
TOTAL   10812  -   7440  = 3372
```

---

The new reps can be found at the bottom of those reports:

- https://stackoverflow.com/reputation
- https://serverfault.com/reputation
- https://superuser.com/reputation
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: Could you add a small section on the final changes, please?

Comment: Remember that the rep-report for MSO shows +5 question upvotes, which won't be included when the change is rolled out. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43008#43008

Comment: @MPelletier: Someone did it for me.

Comment: Does  anyone know when these momentous changes are actually going to happen? I would have thought the weekend was the obvious time, but apparently not.

Comment: @Neil: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43140/how-do-i-know-who-the-rolling-recalc-has-yet-happened-for

Answer (score 6):

Looks like I'm set to lose almost 6k rep total, most of it from SO. I think this is likely due to the two highly-ranked questions that were migrated to Meta and deleted from SO that I still retained points for - the pre-migration rep will cease to exist on either site upon the recalc.

Interestingly, after the recalc my Meta rep will have surpassed my SO rep:

```
SITE  Recalc  - Current = Change (%)
SF    540     - 687     = -147   (-21%)
SO    14252   - 19060   = -4808  (-25%)
SU    1415    - 1600    = -185   (-11%)
MSO   15572   - 16178   = -606   (-4%)
TOTAL 31779   - 37525   = -5746  (-15%)
```

By and large, it seems like I'm the hardest hit so far.

**edit:** Looks like the new https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation now reflects the Meta-specific rep rules.

Comment: That is defiantly something I didn't think about (migrated questions).

Comment: I think Edward Tanguay is No.1 - http://stackoverflow.com/users/4639/edward-tanguay

Comment: @Dexter: it's only significant because there hasn't been a global reputation recalculation in... well, at least eight months, but perhaps never.

Answer (score 3):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SO   51084   - 50081  = 1003 (-2.0%)
```

I know, I know, "Boo hoo hoo," right?  :)

Comment: Had you dropped under 50k it might've been a devastating psychological blow, and I, for one, am thankful to have avoided the aftermath.

Comment: @Gnome: We still have time to get all our downvoting in. ;)

Answer (score 3):

For SO, the only site on which I actively collect reputation:

```
Current  -  Recalc  =  Loss
 34,288  -  37,444  =  -3,156 (9.2% gain)
```

Woo hoo!!

Comment: How'd you **gain** rep?

Comment: Very nearly the same for me.  You gain rep if you regularly hit the rep cap.

Comment: @Maxim: You gain rep if your answer was accepted before hitting the cap.  (Because acceptance bonuses are now fully immune)  I've been surpassing the cap daily for three months, so...

Answer (score 2):

Not much change.

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SF   20289   - 19896  = 393  (-1.9%)
SO   4336    - 3792   = 544 (-12.5%)
SU   503     - 443    = 60  (-11.9%)
MSO  397     - 368    = 29   (-7.3%)
```

Comment: I like your formatting a lot better then my original version.

Answer (score 2):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SO   26558   - 26767  = -209
SF     307   -   298  =    9
SU     206   -   194  =   12
MSO  30314   - 29817  =  497
```

AFAIK, I only lose about 75 on SO from the reduced question rep, more than made up for by the new rep-cap rules.

Comment: I didn't know about the new Rep cap rules. Maybe that's why I'm losing less on SO than I thought I should.

Answer (score 2):

Percentage wise I'm pretty wiped. I think retroactivity by itself would be fair (after all, they should be able to update the scoring system), but the way it combines with bounties really isn't - its just like letting people spend money they don't have. I don't know how I'm losing 54% on meta when the the weighting isn't being changed though.

```
SITE  Current - Recalc = LOST
------------------------------------
SO    2023      928      1095 (54%)
SU    526       306      220 (41%)
MSO   459       205      254 (55%)
------------------------------------
TOTAL                    1569 (including MSO)
```

Comment: The rep-report script for meta assumes meta will be changing to +5 question upvotes too.  It's the script that's off.

Answer (score 2):

```
SITE  Current - Recalc = LOST  
SO     11,560 - 11,187 =  373 (3.2%)  
MSO    10,477 - 10,052 =  425 (4.1%)
```

PS. My SO rep has now been recalculated, and I find myself on the same [page of users](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=13) that I was yesterday (I seem to have moved up by no more than a dozen places actually). So for me it was a virtual no-op.

Answer (score 2):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
------------------------------------
SO    40066  -  44761 = -4695
```

Hehehe, not bad :)

Comment: Yeah, you're now on the 1st page with the users! :)

Comment: @BalusC Oh, indeed :) Pretty cool recalc!

Answer (score 2):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SO   5410    - 3947   = 1463 (=27%, sob!)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SO   15266   - 15246  = 20
MSO  7425    - 6541   = 884
```

SO change was small, but actually smaller than I thought. I took nearly a 1k hit on Meta though. Thankfully, Rep means nothing here. ;)

Comment: As at first I thought this was happening on Meta as well, I was far more upset about having privileges revoked than about losing the rep. There will be a ton of people on SO who will go under 3k or 2k after the recalc. There are probably some people who will go from > 3k to < 1k.

Comment: and at least some people that (deservingly) will go from over 5k to under 2k.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess I'll post mine in the format everyone's using.

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SO   1351    - 931    = 420  (-31.0%)
SF   1       - 1      = 0
SU   407     - 322    = 85
MSO  888     - 443    = 445  (-50.1%)
```

I lost more on MSO than on SO, but it doesn't matter here. Looks like I haven't really participated on SF that much... :(

**Total lost: 950 rep points (counting MSO)**

:'(

Comment: you won't lose as much on meta as the report suggests. question votes will still be worth +10 on meta.

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SO   704     - 561    = 143 (-20.3%)
SF   101     - 101    =   0
SU   101     - 101    =   0
MSO  133     - 123    =  10
```

Sometimes, oddly, it pays to not be active...

BTW, there's no linking bonus for MSO, right?

Comment: @Gnome: you need +200 on the other account you are associating with.

Comment: @MPelletier: The order in which you link apparently matters: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus/5984#5984 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29295/rep-bonus-for-associating-accounts-lost-if-you-associate-early/30370#30370 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-reputation-bonuses-for-associations-between-accounts-work/5918#5918

Comment: @Gnome. Thanks. I redid it and now have more MSO cred!

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully this isn't happening on Meta.

```
SITE  Current  - Recalc = LOST
-------------------------------
SO       5192  -   4576 =  616
SF        101  -    101 =    0
SU        111  -    106 =    5
MSO      3145  -   2419 =  726
-------------------------------
TOTAL    8549 -    7202 = 1347
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE  Current - Recalc = LOST
SO    25182   - 25419  = -237  (+0.1%)
SF      312   - 238    =   74
SU      126   - 126    =    0
MSO    5875   - 5571   =  304  (-5.1%)
-----------------------------
Total                     141 (including Meta)
```

I just had a recalc done on SO at my own request and lost a little over 400 rep, so I will be getting a chunk of it back now. The most significant hit in terms of percentage is at SF, but I really don't belong there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not much is changing for me.

```
SITE  Current - Recalc = LOST
SO     12,379 -  12016 =  363 (-2.9%)
SU         63 -     58 =    5
SF        101 -    101 =    0
```

I'm also [ranked 385](http://so.chrisballance.com/) on SO, I'm interested in how it changes after the recalc.

Comment: Went up to position 382, but the differences are too small anyway for it to matter. Anyway, good job everyone.

Answer (score 1):

For the record:

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST  
SO   17751   - 16818  = 933  (-5.3%)
SF     640   -   576  =  64  (-10%)
SU     263   -   208  =  55  (-21%)
MSO   2577   -  2054  = 523  (-20%)
```

Answer (score 1):

SO is the only site where I'd notice (or even care about) a hit. Depending on what happens between now and then:

```
Current - Recalc  = LOST
8172      7450      722  (-8.8%)
```

About 1.5 month's worth of rep for me, given the frequency where I find time to use the site. I'm not losing any functionality, so its nothing to cry over. Reaching 10k will just take a month or so longer, no big deal.

**I, for one, welcome our new rep system overlords.** The thing is, as many questions have already been asked, it is increasingly harder to reach the high rep spectrum by just asking lots of questions *anyway*. That will just continue over time.

May as well make it fair. I'm not shedding any tears.

---

Yep, I hit it dead on. I'm now at [7472](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) but had a few votes on answers prior to the recalc. Its all good, I'll be even happier when I manage to hit 10k.

---

I'll wait for the next DB dump, but looking over things, it seems like this had the exact intended result.

Comment: Yes, but I just recently saw a person with over 8000 rep ask a horribly made question and when I looked on their profile, over 700 questions and less than 70 answers...

Comment: @eartz: Yes, that's what this new system hopes to prevent. You can still earn lots of rep by asking good questions, but 1 - the question can't already have been asked and 2 - the resulting rep is not artificially inflated. This is good, it means people that get to the high end of the scale have likely provided good technical answers to good technical questions.

Answer (score 1):

Including Meta:

```
 SITE   Current  - Recalc  = LOST
 SO    26,055   - 29,882   = -3827 
 MSO    2,704   -  2,332   =   380
 SF       301   -    236   =    65 
 SU       161   -     71   =    90
 ----------------------------------
                             -3292
```

Comment: Are you sure you have your SO statistics the right way around?

Comment: @Jonathan yup! Must have got a lot of accepted answers early in the day.

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
------------------------------------
SO   14201   - 14266  =  -65
SF     161   -   161  =    0
SU     217   -   209  =    8
MSO   2245   -  2268  =  -23 (just for reference)
------------------------------------
TOTAL                    -80
```

Almost no change, and all my points on SF, SU are from migrated questions from SO

Answer (score 1):

oh, what the hell.  not much change, but for statistical porpoises (cause porpoises rock):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST  
----------------------------
SO     396   -   309  =  87  
SF     579   -   555  =  24  
SU   12416   - 12422  =  -8  
MSO   1913   -  1545  = 368  
---------------------------
total                   471 lost and a complete part of a balanced breakfast
```

Comment: ...just not *my* balanced breakfast.  i had waffles.

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST  
-----------------------
SU   10585   - 10230   = 355 (-3%)
```

Could be worse.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm down about 200 on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SO   45423   - 44921  =  498
```

I lose some because of the reduced up-votes on questions; I lose some more because of votes for now deleted questions, etc.  I gain some back because of the 'accepted' answers not being part of the daily limit any more.  I had been wondering whether I needed to request a recalc; now I don't have to because it will happen anyway.

Maybe the site should do a recalc for each user every month or so - it could be batched over the entire month, rather than all at once.  And a statistic on the rep page could be 'date/time of last rep recalc'.

The other three sites are 'unchanged'.

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE  Current  - Recalc  = LOST
-------------------------------
SO      30324  -  35270  = none
SF        131  -    131  = none
SU        101  -    101  = none
MSO       468  -    295  =  173
```

Look like I've pretty a lot of accepted answers at SO and questions at MSO.

Comment: your math is off.  30324-35270 == -4946 != 0.

Comment: @~quack: that's not a `LOST` :)

Comment: Good "boost" too, well done :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I think I'm reading this correctly..

> Before: 4958. After: 3465 Difference:
>   1493

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE  Current - Recalc = LOST
SO     8736   - 8400   =  336  (-3.8 %)
SF       99   - 101    =   -2
SU      127   - 128    =   -2
MSO     367   - 288    =   81  (-22.1 %)
-----------------------------
Total                     413 (including Meta)
```

The hit on SO is isn't massive but it surely isn't nice to lose rep ;-)

I got 26 upvotes on my questions (combined) so that would explain for a 130 loss from the 336 loss on SO. Not sure where the 206 other rep points went to (migrated questions maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE  Current  - Recalc  = LOST
-------------------------------
SO        537  -    473  =   64 (-11.9%)
SF        217  -    218  =   -1 (+0.46%)
SU       5186  -   5117  =   69 (-1.33%)
MSO      2288  -   1984  =  304 (-13.2%)
-------------------------------
TOTAL    8228  -   7792  =  436 (-5.29%)
```

Well, I guess you can see where I'm most active! Looks like I'm losing my retag ability on SO...

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't affect me that much, but here is how it affects me:

```
SITE  Current  - Recalc  = LOST
-------------------------------
SO       694  -    685  =    9 (-1.29%)
SF       627  -    583  =   44 (-7.02%)
SU      1700  -   1702  =   -2 (+0.12%)
MSO       75  -     77  =   -2 (+0.26%)
-------------------------------
TOTAL   3096  -   3047  =   49 (-1.58%)
```

Not sure why I am loosing 9 rep on SO when I have no question votes, but it's only 9 rep and it's not like I can do anything about it, so I don't really care. :)

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have been hit rather hard... bye bye moderator tools. :(

```
SITE  Current  - Recalc  = LOST
-------------------------------
SO      11955  -   8732  = 3223 (-27%)
MSO     11061  -   7937  = 3124 (-28%)
```

At least it isn't affecting Meta...

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SU   7012    - 6198   = 814
```

Couldn't care less. I still think of these forums as modifiable Usenet / Fidonet. :-)
But I do think these sites are lately changing too fast: should slow down a little, and
do not change anything for a while to stabilize the system. They're becoming overly complicated.

Comment: @Gnome - I don't understand your comment in edit.

Comment: @Gnome - ah, ok. Btw, I ment SU (http://superuser.com/users/rep-report).

Comment: Just checking, since you had your SO account associated, but not SU.

Comment: @Gnome - Oh, ... well, I just associated that one to copy the data. Is there a point in associating every one with every one on every site ? ... the rep recalc just kicked in ... wow, I actually fell one whole place in the users list :))

Answer (score 1):

SO: 19,889 - 17,789 = 2100

Answer (score 1):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SO   17,928  - 20,043 = -2,115 (+11.79%)
```

Comment: Test teest test test test test

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack Overflow
--------------
Before:   3170
After:    3101
--------------
Lost:       69 (-2.2%)
```

I only answered questions on SO and didn't ask any; the lost points are from answers I've deleted. The nice thing is that I'm still over 3k. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SO   4781   - 4114  = 667 (-14.0%)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = LOST
SO   14,543   - 13,541  = 1,002 (-6.89%)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SITE Current - Recalc = Change
SO   9241    - 9311   =  -70   (gained)
```

I'm most active on SO so rep on all other SOFU sites are unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was expecting to lose somewhere around 120 and I lost over twice that on SO - I think that's most likely largely due to some questions that got migrated later. The loss on the others was about what I estimated.

I wonder if it would be possible (in future) to show 'Rep Recalc' and the effect of it in a user's Recent section.

Ok, now I've got an additional puzzle - my Reputation link shows my overall total to be almost 286 less than is actually showing, and an answer I got 290 rep for has now vanished (I can't find the question either, although I'm unsure of its precise title). Getting confused...

Answer (score -1):

```
SITE  Current  - Recalc  = LOST
-------------------------------
SO       2675  -   2653  =   22  (-0.82%)
SF        101  -    101  =    0
SU        101  -    101  =    0
MSO       256  -    256  =    0
-------------------------------
TOTAL    3133 -    3111  =   22  (-0.70%)
```

**Update:** I lost 10 more points, probably due to an upvote by a user whose account has been deleted in the mean time. I have also climbed 10 pages up in the Users tab.