# This is an outrage! Why did I just gain +70 rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, fun, reputation-recalc

A few days ago I had 9241 rep on SO. Upon returning to the site I discovered I had mysteriously gained 70 points. Further inspection reveals that I had no upvotes or accepted answers.

I feel my rep has been incorrectly inflated giving a false sense of my worth and the quality of my answers. This also makes me reach the 10K tools quicker than expected, and I wasn't planning on being distracted with those new capabilities so soon!

I discovered the great rep-calc post and I feel somewhat guilty participating in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43110/post-how-much-rep-youre-going-to-lose-with-the-new-re-calc) since I didn't "lose" anything. Well, I did lose my lower rep, so I guess that's a compromise. I think the change shouldn't have been retroactive. Just award my future points according to this new algorithm.

If you feel as cheated as I do I suggest we band together by wearing [this T-shirt](http://shirt.woot.com/Friends.aspx?k=5338) till the official SO T-shirts are available <sub>(I have no affiliation w/this site etc.)</sub>:

[image: Fat Unicorn]

Now that my coffee's ready I can stop wasting my time on meta :)

Comment: I don't really understand why there is an overweight unicorn eating our T-Shirts, but anyway. +1.

Comment: That is *OUTRAGEOUS!!*

Comment: @jeff - I *completely* agree - why would a unicorn eat it's own waste? Ludicrous!

Comment: @Pekka it's symbolism: the blue (err, green) sky and rainbows represent the status quo and we're left picking up the pieces of the shattered world we once knew. The unicorn packing extra pounds represents the undeserved rep gain. Sad, sad world.

Comment: fantastic :) ..

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I must make you gain more rep.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Nooooooooooo!!! (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tim5nU3DwIE)

Comment: This is the *only* "complaint about rep recalc" question that I upvoted. Thanks for making my day a little brighter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the Destroyer of Ponies ate a few too many:

[image: "unicorn, destroyer of ponies"]

Comment: There can be only one: http://www.idwpublishing.com/news/article/904/

Comment: I bow before your Mad Photoshoping Skillz!

Comment: You can get a print of this picture for $52 here: http://www.society6.com/studio/devinmcgrath/Unicorn_Destroyer_of_Ponies

Comment: Robot unicorn trumps regular unicorn: http://games.adultswim.com/robot-unicorn-attack-twitchy-online-game.html

Answer (score 7):

If you think **+70** is **OUTRAGEOUS**, do **not** follow [@jonskeet](https://twitter.com/jonskeet).

Comment: The actual tweet in question: https://twitter.com/jonskeet/status/10888131165 (I'd considered editing your post, but thought better of it.)

Comment: Haha. Am I the only one that gets this? Oh, nvm.

Comment: Nice. I missed that; haven't been on twitter today :)

Comment: Hahahahahahahaha! I wish Jon had posted that, just to spite us. He'd been stoned to death by the poor souls who lost half their reputation. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's due to solar flares and an unprecedented solar eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

I agree.  I lost over -1500 points.  I demand satisfaction!

How *dare* you retroactively award reputation for the time I spent answering questions after receiving bounties.  This, good sir, will *not* stand.

Comment: A loss of -1500 - you have my condolances sir. Your empathy for the op must be crippling for you.

Comment: Wow, and I thought I had it bad! I join @Farseeker and offer my deepest condolences!

Comment: @Farseeker: I had to run for 80 stack-hours on a stack-treadmill to lose those stack-pounds, and now it's like I just gorged myself on 28 tubs of stack-ice cream. Not fair!

Comment: Lol @ downvote, I think somebody's bitter. :P

Comment: Ya a bunch of downvotes all around it seems. I got 3 so far!

Comment: I gained about 200. How's that for ya? Smelly enough? Let me rub that a bit harder in you face. There we go.