# "Legions of insanely-pedantic users": not against the be-nice policy?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

I read the following [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267239/will-stack-exchange-sites-always-be-freely-accessible/267356#comment867283_267356) (the comment has now been deleted, so here is the [mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170308011058/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267239/will-stack-exchange-sites-always-be-freely-accessible/267356#comment867283_267356)) on meta:

> So far everyone has missed the REAL reason why SE sites will always be freely-accessible: legions of insanely-pedantic users.

Doesn't it go against the be-nice policy (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice: "Name-calling. Focus on the post, not the person", "Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.", etc.)?

I flagged the comment but it got declined without any explanation.

---

For the non-native English speakers: [Is the use of the adjective “pedantic” always derogatory?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/99838/3023)

Comment: I think you took the comment to be a lot more serious than it is intended to be.

Comment: I know some people who might consider "insanely pedantic" to be a compliment. Some people are proud of their pedantry.

Comment: Finally! This Shog9 dude has gotten away with his shenanigans for far too long.

Comment: [Why are some jokes closed and deleted and others are allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43969/why-are-some-jokes-closed-and-deleted-and-others-are-allowed)

Comment: So is it a joke or a complement? (also, I believe "focus on the post, not the person" should regardless still apply, otherwise it creates noise in the discussion)

Comment: All of the above?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"Insanely pedantic" is not a value judgement. It's a descriptor, which doesn't have an inherent negative connotation. It's roughly on the same level as saying "The reason why SO works is because of the legions of very active and thorough people".

Moreover, that was a comment made by a community manager. When in doubt, you should assume that they know what they're doing. After all, they have a significant hand in making the rules that you cite.

That comment is not worth deleting.

ps: I would count myself among those "insanely pedantic" users, and I'd take that as a compliment, not an insult :p

Comment: I'll remember this and call you insanely pedantic forty two times a day.

Comment: ok, I'll add it to my list of compliments then.

Comment: You have a typo there in "insanely pendantic". I know, I'm just being pedantic - we all know what you mean.

Comment: @Oded edited. *grumbles something into the coffee*

Comment: You missed a spot ;)

Comment: @Oded It's completely possible that Magisch would prefer to spend the afternoon on a swing.

Comment: At this point, that might be the appropriate response, @Catija

Comment: *grumbles* @Oded I await anxiously that you tell me there are other minor spelling errors in that post >_>

Comment: Dunno about that. Shall we move to grammar?

Comment: @Oded Maybe have mercy on my non native speaker english skills. I know its not that good.

Comment: As one non native speaker to another - sure :)