# Massive Score Drop?

Tags: support, score

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The global reputation recalc of March 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010)

I hadn't logged into the site for about a month and my score is has dropped by over a thousand points!

By reading other similar questions, it seems that drops in score are usually caused by scripts that detect fraudulent voting, but I've had the score for a while now and this seems different.

What's happened? It'd be nice to receive a notification when your score drops that much.

Comment: Hey, don't thrash *this* poster. He evidently did *some* reading before posting. That puts him on up on certain others.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [rule change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) and scores dropped because everyones score was recalculated.

Here is the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010). You can read more about it [here as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43110/post-how-much-rep-youre-going-to-lose-with-the-new-re-calc).

Comment: Hey, what gives the downvote?

Comment: The downvote is to signify that we, instead of pointing out the duplicate in the comment, and voting to close the question as a duplicate like good boys, chose to make it a (totally superfluous) answer instead, in the hopes of harvesting some ill-gotten reputation. :)

Comment: You know, since I have a low score, I don't have the authority to vote a question to close which is why I can't help with marking it as a duplicate. However any reasoning I can think of why downvoting an answer, especially one that was correct and helpful, seems like a move that a jerk would make. As of right now, two jerks. :)

Comment: @Spoike don't take it too seriously. This is Meta, and voting habits (and answering habits) are different to SO proper. A downvote is seen more as a sign of disagreement, and not necessarily an unhelpful answer.

Comment: If you are posting on an obvious duplicate you can add a comment or you can mark it as CW...

Comment: That's one of the quickest Godwins I've seen, and all for something that doesn't matter, since these dupe questions are eventually deleted and the rep changes reversed during the next recalc.

Comment: Actually, I usually downvote answers on dupes on SO too.  Sorry to be a jerk, but spreading answers across multiple questions just makes  it harder to find answers and makes more cleanup work later to merge the content.

Comment: @Spoike, don't let the comment nazis get to you.  You're welcome to have this as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

There was a [recalculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010).